Construction of exceptional functors $f_!$ (and $f^!$) when not finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$
Clausen and Scholze introduced the concept of an analytic ring, leading to the following results:
Theorem (Clausen-Scholze)
(1) If $R$ is a　finitely generatedalgebra over $\mathbb{Z}$, then the pre-analytic ring $R_{\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}$ becomes an analytic ring.
(2) Given a morphism $f: X \to Y$ between schemes finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$, there exist exceptional functors $f_!: D(\mathcal{O}_{X,\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}) \to D(\mathcal{O}_{Y,\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}})$ and $f^!: D(\mathcal{O}_{Y,\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}) \to D(\mathcal{O}_{X,\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}})$.
My question is, how are the exceptional functors $f_!$ and $f^!$ constructed when $R$, $X$ and $Y$ are not finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$? I would appreciate any specific construction methods or related theories.
In particular, I am interested in the case where we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with a discrete field of characteristic $0$ and consider algebras or schemes finitely generated over this field.
Scholze and Clausen do provide a footnote regarding the case when $R$ is not finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$, but it seems their lecture notes do not address the existence of exceptional functors $f_!$ (and $f^!$) or whether the pre-analytic ring $R_{\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}$ becomes analytic.

We discuss this in more detail in our Analytic Stacks course. The functor $f_!$ exists for all $!$-able maps of analytic rings, which includes $(R,R)\blacksquare\to (S,S)\blacksquare$ whenever $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra. It satisfies all the same properties as in the case where both are of finite type over $\mathbb Z$; this can be proved, for example, by "noetherian approximation" (the functor $f_!$ commutes with any base change).

Thank you very much!
